# Probability you can walk from point $A$ to point $B$

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Consider the following map of roads below.  Each of the $5$ roads are labeled.  On any given day, each road is open independently of the others with probability $1/3.$  [image]

$\textbf{My first question:}$

> What is the probability, on any given day, a person can walk from point $A$ to point $B$?

My initial thought was to just add the probabilities 
$$\mathbb{P}(R_{1})\mathbb{P}(R_{4}) + \mathbb{P}(R_{2})\mathbb{P}(R_{5}) + \mathbb{P}(R_{1})\mathbb{P}(R_{3})\mathbb{P}(R_{5}) + \mathbb{P}(R_{2})\mathbb{P}(R_{3})\mathbb{P}(R_{4}). \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

This comes out to $\frac{8}{27}.$  However, for some reason, I feel like I am double counting something.

$\textbf{My second question:}$

> Given that a person can walk from point $A$ to point $B$, what is the probability that road number $3$ is open?

This kind of gives me Bayes' Rule vibes.  Let $Y$ be the event that it is possible to walk from point $A$ to point $B.$  Let $T$ be the event that road number $3$ is open.  We have 
$$\mathbb{P}(T\mid Y)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(Y\mid T)\mathbb{P}(T)}{\mathbb{P}(Y\mid T)\mathbb{P}(T)+\mathbb{P}(Y\mid T^{C})\mathbb{P}(T^{C})}. \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
 \ \ \ \ (2)$$

Plugging in $\mathbb{P}(R_{3})=1$ to expression $(1)$, $\mathbb{P}(Y\mid T)$ becomes $\frac{4}{9}.$  If it is possible to walk from point $A$ to point $B$ given road number $3$ is closed, then $\mathbb{P}(Y\mid T^{C})= \mathbb{P}(R_{1})\mathbb{P}(R_{4}) + \mathbb{P}(R_{2})\mathbb{P}(R_{5}) = \frac{2}{9}.$  Plugging in these values, equation $(2)$ simplifies to $\frac{1}{2}.$

Again, I do not know why, but I feel my work is colossally wrong.  Anyone want to give it a second look?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your first question, you successfully figure out that the event is equivalent to the union of 4 events - the 4 possible paths is open. But you cannot simply break them as a sum since those 4 events are not mutually exclusive. You need to apply inclusion-exclusion to avoid double-counting.

Comment: @BGM Yep, I knew I was double counting stuff. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, you're double-counting in the sense that the events whose probabilities you're adding in $(1)$ aren't mutually exclusive.

In $(1)$, you want $\mathsf P((R_1\cap R_4)\cup(R_2\cap R_5)\cup(R_1\cap R_3\cap R_5)\cup(R_2\cap R_3\cap R_4))$. You can evaluate this using [inclusion–exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) as

\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\mathsf P((R_1\cap R_4)\cup(R_2\cap R_5)\cup(R_1\cap R_3\cap R_5)\cup(R_2\cap R_3\cap R_4))\\
&=&
\mathsf P(R_1\cap R_4)+\mathsf P(R_2\cap R_5)+\mathsf P(R_1\cap R_3\cap R_5)+\mathsf P(R_2\cap R_3\cap R_4)-\mathsf P((R_1\cap R_4)\cap(R_2\cap R_5))\\
&&-\cdots-P((R_1\cap R_4)\cap(R_2\cap R_5)\cap(R_1\cap R_3\cap R_5)\cap(R_2\cap R_3\cap R_4))\\
&=&
3^{-2}+3^{-2}+3^{-3}+3^{-3}-3^{-4}-3^{-4}-3^{-4}-3^{-4}-3^{-4}-3^{-5}+4\cdot3^{-5}-3^{-5}=\frac{59}{243}\;,
\end{eqnarray*}

and likewise for the probabilities you need to apply Bayes's rule in $(2)$.

*Edit*:

Actually, your calculation in part $2$ suggests an easier way to calculate the probabilty in part $1$. This is $\mathsf P(Y)$, the denominator in part $2$, and we don't need the full inclusion–exclusion machinery to evaluate that:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathsf P(Y)
&=&
\mathsf P(Y\mid T)\mathsf P(T)+\mathsf P(Y\mid \overline T)\mathsf P(\overline T)
\\
&=&
\mathsf P((R_1\cup R_2)\cap(R_4\cup R_5))\mathsf P(R_3)+\mathsf P((R_1\cap R_4)\cup(R_2\cap R_5))\mathsf P(\overline{R_3})
\\
&=&
\left(1-\left(1-\frac13\right)^2\right)^2\cdot\frac13+\left(1-\left(1-\left(\frac13\right)^2\right)^2\right)\cdot\frac23
\\
&=&
\frac{25}{81}\cdot\frac13+\frac{17}{81}\cdot\frac23
\\
&=&
\frac{59}{243}\;,
\end{eqnarray*}

in agreement with the previous result.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! Do you mind writing out the probabilities so I can understand a little better? If not, no big deal.

Comment: @StatGuy: I don't really feel like writing **all** of them out :-), but I wrote out some; I hope that's enough for you to fill in the rest -- just form all the pairs and triplets; I tried to do them in lexical order so you can match them with the powers of $3$. I combined all the triplets into a single term $4\cdot3^{-5}$ because they all contain all five roads.

Comment: So helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @StatGuy: Looking at your calculation for $(2)$ again, I just saw that you're making the denominator too complicated. The expression in the denominator is correct, and sometimes you need this form to find the denominator, but it's just $\mathsf P(Y)$, and you already calculated that in the first part; no need to calculate $P(Y\mid\overline T)$ (though that's straightforward and your result for it is correct).

Comment: @StatGuy: Actually, come to think of it, this provides a simpler way to calculate $\mathsf P(Y)$, since $\mathsf P(Y\mid T)$ can be calculated without the full inclusion–exclusion machinery as

$$\mathsf P((R_1\cup R_2)\cap(R_4\cup R_5))=\left(1-\left(1-\frac13\right)^2\right)^2=\frac{25}{81}\;.$$

Comment: By brute force method, I am getting a probability of 0.226 for part a) and 0.381 for part (b)

Comment: @SatishRamanathan: I just rederived the result $\frac{59}{243}\approx0.243$ for the first part by an independent method (see the edit), so it seems unlikely that it's wrong.

Comment: So, my denominator in part $2$ is equal to $8/27$, which, is wrong. So how did I get the correct result for part $2$?

Comment: @StatGuy: I don't think your result in the second part is correct -- why do you think so? I only said that your result for $P(Y\mid\overline T)$ is correct. I believe the correct result for the second part is

$$
\mathsf P(T\mid Y)=\frac{\mathsf P(Y\mid T)\mathsf P(T)}{\mathsf P(Y)}=\frac{\frac{25}{81}\cdot\frac13}{\frac{59}{243}}=\frac{25}{59}\;.
$$

By the way, I edited the answer to show the simpler way to do the first part, based on the denominator in the second part.

Comment: You are right, I found a calculation error.  Sorry and thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 0):

Brute force method:  I have listed all possible combination of the gates to be open and it is $2^5 = 32$ ways these gates could be open or closed.

[image]

Comment: Your result for $R_2=R_3=R_4=1$, $R_1=R_5=0$ is wrong; $J$ should be $1$ in this case.

Comment: @ I have corrected it and now the answer concurs with @joriki